# Fill between and soft clipping doesn't work as expected

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I am trying to visualize the oriented area under a curve using pgfplots like in the following example. However the output is messed up. What's wrong here and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.13,
axis lines=center,
samples=100
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=0.49\textwidth]
    \addplot[name path = f] gnuplot {cos(x)};%
    \addplot[name path = x] gnuplot {0};

    %\addplot fill between[of=f and x,split,soft clip={domain=-2:4}];
    \addplot fill between[of=f and x,soft clip={domain=-2:4}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The split options makes it a bit better but doesn't produce a correct picture too.

Comment: I'll consider this as a bug, because when you comment the line `axis lines=center,` it works as expected. I'll write a bug report for that in a minute.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks. Please post a link to the bug report.

Comment: The bug is recorded at <https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/111/>

Comment: @StefanPinnow Your link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The link address in principle is correct, but for whatever reason the `>` isn't marking the end of the link but now is part of it. So if you click on the link just remove the `>` in the address line of your browser and it will work.

Comment: For the record: With the release of PGFPlots v1.16 your example gives the expected result.

Answer (score 5):

Not the real solution but a by-pass: Plot the function as usual and again with the domain restricted to the clipping interval:

```
\documentclass{article}%[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.13,
axis lines=center,
every fill between plot/.append style={fill=blue,fill opacity=0.2},
samples=100
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=0.49\textwidth]
    \addplot[name path = fcurve] gnuplot {cos(x)};%
    \addplot[name path = f,domain=-2:4] {cos(x)};%
    \addplot[name path = g,domain=-2:4] {0};
    \addplot [blue] fill between[of=f and g];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was the way I have done it before I have seen soft clipping. The obvious problem with this is that you have do do everything twice with tends to get painful... Though it doesn't answer my question, it might be helpful for others reading this post.

Comment: @student: Of course ... as I wrote: Only a work-around. I am sure that there is a better solution, but I can't provide it :-(

Comment: compiling your solution I receive error "Runaway argument ...". If I add semicolon after last `addplot ...` than I receive error: " missing number, treated as zero ..."

Comment: @Zarko: Yes, thanks. I edited the code and removed some options, apparently the semicolon was deleted too. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems a problem with the range y. You may want to setup ymin and ymax. 
For example, replacing `\begin{axis}[width=0.49\textwidth]` by `\begin{axis}[ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, width=0.49\textwidth]` should work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{
     compat=1.13,
     axis lines=center,
     samples=100
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     ymin=-1.5,
     ymax=1.5,
     width=0.49\textwidth]
\addplot[name path = f] {cos(deg(x))};%
\addplot[name path = x] {0};
\addplot fill between[of=f and x,soft clip={domain=-2:4}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great idea to set the y range. It seems that setting the limits to -1 and 1 also fails, but setting them to -1.01 and 1.01 also gives the desired result. That sounds like a rounding issue. I'll add that as a note to the [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/111/).